# Android Studio - AVD system images

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed Android Studio on my local Debian machine. I had a plethora of problems related to various paths for locating parts of the suite but I finally got the IDE working. I started building an app but now AVD has lost or cannot find any system images. I need to know where AVD is looking so I can change the path or move my system images to a place where AVD can find them. Any suggestions?

Android Studio v 2.2.3 on Linux

Answer (score 0):

Generally in Linux, the default path of AVD is `~/.android/avd` or wherever your home directory for Android is. Inside your home directory you will find `.android` folder. Inside that folder, `avd` folder should be present.

`system-images` folder is present where your `SDK` would be installed on the machine. If you want to find your SDK folder path, open `SDK Manager` in Android Studio and it will show the SDK path on the top of the SDK Manager Window.

Go to SDK folder and inside that, there must be a folder named `system-images`. If not, your SDK images are missing. You can download them from SDK manager.